# Django: dropdown selecting a model in a generic view

Tags: python, django

I have a generic Django generic `DetailView` and I'd like to be able to render a dropdown via a `django.form`. The options are a list of objects that belong to the user. I can do this for ALL objects with something like `Model.objects.all()` in the form, but how can I filter out the options that belong to the user without being able to access the `request.user` from the form?

I've seen an example where the queryset can be injected into the form:

```
form = MyForm()
form['field'].queryset = Model.objects.filter(user=user)
```

But there is no place to really do this in a django generic view (is there?)

Comment: This looks more like an `UpdateView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do the same trick in a `DetailView`, or you can alter your model to accept a parameter.

For example we can override the `get_context_data` method with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import DetailView

class SomeView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = SomeModel

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        form = MyModelForm()
        form['some_field'].queryset = Model.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        context.update(form=form)
        return context
```

A `DetailView` with a form is often an [**`UpdateView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView), given that form thus handles the same model of the model in your `DetailView`. You might consider looking into that.